# Is there a way to bring the terminal to the front when whatever I launched is done?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

So I'm wondering if It was possible to bring in front my terminal when what I ran is now done.

I'm not taking about a one time stuff like

> run_long_task; bring_to_front_somehow;

but something that would do it automatically.

This would greatly improved my productivity :)

I'm using zshell(if that helps)

Comment: I think using a dropdown terminal Guake or Tilda is the easiest way, although not exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it working.

So I had to find a way to plug in to the prompt display.

So basicly in my zsh theme I added a method to bring to the front the current window.

```
function bring_to_front {
  xdotool windowactivate $WINDOWID
}
```

$WINDOWID is actually set by gnome-terminal automatically.

and the magic is just to call that method as part of the prompt. this way everytime the prompt is displayed, it will bring it to the front. And since the prompt is displayed when the previous command is finished...

```
PROMPT='$(bring_to_front)${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'
```

The next thing I'm trying to achieve is to select the right tab. I will update the answer if I get that working.

EDIT

**Bonus
Switch to the right tab**

Disclaimer : This is hacky as hell so bear with me.

*this works only for gnome terminal.*

```
function alert_done {
  xdotool windowactivate $WINDOWID
  child_count=`pgrep --parent $PPID -c`
  # we need to remove the first child as it's gnome-tty-helper and not a tab
  terminal_count=`expr $child_count - 1`
  terminal_pids=`pgrep --parent $PPID | tail -n $terminal_count | tr '\n' ' '`
  eval "pid_array=($terminal_pids)"
  xdotool key alt+${(k)pid_array[(r)$$]}
}
```

Comment: If you found the solution to your question, you might as well mark/accept your answer then (:

Comment: Must have missed out on that one. Be patient then!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install `wmctrl` which is a command line tool to interact with an
EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

In order to focus the right Terminal, you'll need to start it with a given title, like this:

```
gnome-terminal -t tototiti
```

Then you can bring it to the front with the following command:

```
sleep 10; wmctrl -a tototiti
```

**Note**: `wmctrl -a STRING` gives focus to a window containing STRING in its title

Tested with both `bash` and `zsh`

Comment: Thanks but like I said in my question I'm looking for something that would be automatic. meaning I don't have to add "; wmctrl foo" everytime.

Comment: As you need interaction with the X stack you'll necessarily need such program, if not wmctrl, it can be xdotool but I honestly doubt that an "automatic" mode exists.

Comment: I know that my zsh plugins, parse the directory and if I'm in a git repo change the display to show which branch I'm in and such. Maybe I can plug into that check to trigger that "bring to front magic"